# Grouping of values in sql

Tags: sql

My dataset looks like this:

```
  Id      MaxSpeed      Distance
  1       112           33
  1       89            56
  2       100           34
  3       125           10
```

For each Id, I need to set up the count as 1.

Output has to be

```
  Id  count
  1   1
  2   1
  3   1
```

I tried with group by on Id, it does not fetch me this result.

Any help would be really appreciated !!

Comment: What are you counting here exactly?  It's not clear how your desired output relates to the data.  For example, you have two rows with an ID of 1, but you want the count to be one?

Comment: The queries below used `distinct` but you could also have used `group by` the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the count always need to be 1? If so, could this query work?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, 1
FROM your_table;
```

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you are overthinking it.

```
Select Distinct ID,1 as Count From YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following sql code:

```
Select distinct Id,1 as count From Table_Name;
```